# .pack file from git repo can't be deleted using File delete() method

Tags: java, git, github, jgit

For this method I am writing, I am cloning a git repo using the jgit library, then doing some stuff with those files, then finally I want to delete the repo.
The problem I'm having is that when I call the delete() method on a .pack file (located in .git\objects\pack), it can't be deleted. All other files can be deleted though. Why does this happen?

Comment: Nevermind, found the solution here: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jgit-dev/msg01961.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I release file system locks after cloning repo via JGit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764311/how-do-i-release-file-system-locks-after-cloning-repo-via-jgit)

Comment: Konwn bug in JGit up to 4.0.1, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764311/how-do-i-release-file-system-locks-after-cloning-repo-via-jgit/31764312?noredirect=1#comment51471054_31764312 for more discussion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see that Java apps based on JGit have a tendency to disble ddd by default.
See this [config file](http://gitblit.com/properties.html) for [**Gitblit**](http://gitblit.com/) for instance:

```
# When true, JGit will use mmap() rather than malloc()+read() to load data from
# pack files. The use of mmap can be problematic on some JVMs as the garbage
# collector must deduce that a memory mapped segment is no longer in use before
# a call to munmap() can be made by the JVM native code.
#
# In server applications (such as Gitblit) that need to access many pack files,
# setting this to true risks artificially running out of virtual address space,
# as the garbage collector cannot reclaim unused mapped spaces fast enough.
#
# Default on JGit is false. Although potentially slower, it yields much more
# predictable behavior.
# Documentation courtesy of the Gerrit project.
#
# SINCE 1.0.0
# RESTART REQUIRED
git.packedGitMmap = false
```

---

This is consistent with the [JGit thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jgit-dev/msg01961.html) you found:

> > I ran into another instance of not being able to delete a cloned repository in windows.
> >     This one appears linked to the use of "`PackedGitMMAP`".
> >     Is this a known problem with trying to use virtual memory mapping?
>
> Yes.
>   The problem is the JVM does not release the memory mapping until the mapping is garbage collected by the Java GC.
>   This can happen at any time in the future, possibly never if there is insufficient memory
>   pressure to force the GC to really look for garbage and reclaim.
>   This is why we disable the feature by default, we can't predict when the JVM will finally release the file.
>
> > In this test case if I "`setPackedGitMMAP=false`" then the repository is deleted successfully.
>
> Yes. This is why this is the default.

Answer (score 11):

Just found a clean way to do it:
After doing stuff with your repo, close your git object this way :

```
Git git;
...
git.getRepository().close();
//then delete files
```

Comment: For anyone who makes the same mistake I did: `git.close()` and `git.getRepository().close()` are not the same! The javadoc seems to imply that `git.close()` will also close the underlying repository but this isn't always the case so it's better to close it explicitly.