# How do I release file system locks after cloning repo via JGit

Tags: java, jgit, filehandle

I am playing around with cloning a remote existing repo with jGit following the guide here:

https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/CloneRemoteRepository.java

I'm using CFML for my example:

```
Git = createObject( 'java', 'org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git' );

localPath = createObject( 'java', 'java.io.File' ).init( expandPath( 'temp' ) );

result = Git.cloneRepository()
        .setURI( 'https://github.com/github/testrepo.git' )
        .setDirectory( localPath )
        .call();

result.close();
```

The clone works great, but file locks are not released on "pack" files inside `temp\.git\objects\pack` until I stop the Java process.

Then I also noticed the API docs seem a little wishy-washy concerning the behavior of the result's `.close()` method.:
http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.0.1.201506240215-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/Repository.html#close()

> Decrement the use count, and maybe close resources.

Maybe?  What's that supposed to mean?  What do I need to do in order to "relinquishing any underlying resources" as specified in the `AutoCloseable` interface that the `.close()` method helps implement?

There are a couple of similar questions on SO, but none of them involve using the static method on `org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git` to clone a new repo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So literally as I was clicking submit on this after a couple days of poking I stumbled across what I believe is the answer.

The cookbook example only calls the `.close()` method on the result of the `cloneRepository()`'s `call()` method (A `Git` instance).  The API docs state that method should also call the `.close` method of the underlying `Repository` instance:

http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.0.1.201506240215-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/Git.html#close()

> If the repository was opened by a static factory method in this class, then this method calls Repository.close() on the underlying repository instance.

However, I found that if I get the `Repository` instance myself and call its `.close()` method, all file system locks are released.  I assume this is an omission in the JGit cookbook reference I was following and will submit an issue/pull.

Here is the working CFML code.  Note the two `.close()` calls at the bottom now.

```
Git = createObject( 'java', 'org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git' );

localPath = createObject( 'java', 'java.io.File' ).init( expandPath( 'temp' ) );

result = Git.cloneRepository()
        .setURI( 'https://github.com/github/testrepo.git' )
        .setDirectory( localPath )
        .call();

result.getRepository().close();
result.close();
```

Comment: So it also is either a bug in either the Git.close() method or its javadoc, maybe you can also raise an issue there to get it corrected/clarified?

Comment: I've love to raise an issue with jGit we well if this is actually a bug in the library (and not just an incomplete example).  I'll make a note to do that later today.

Comment: Yes, I took a quick look, I think there is a small bug in CloneCommand.call(), it should pass "true" as additional parameter when constructing the instance of the Git object to make the closing work as advertised, see also http://git.eclipse.org/c/jgit/jgit.git/tree/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CloneCommand.java#n137

Comment: Additionally, errors during fetch and checkout in that method will leave the repository object unclosed...

Comment: Thanks for checking that out.  I put in a ticket for jGit here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=474093

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with that as well. Here is how I solved this.

```
CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository();
URIish urIish = new URIish(getVersionControlPath().toString());
cloneCommand.setURI(urIish.toString());
Date date = new Date();
String testgit = "testgit_" + date.getTime();
cloneCommand.setDirectory(getVersionControlPath().getParent().resolve(testgit).toFile());
Git call = cloneCommand.call();
call.close();
```